# One fixed and another sticky in a flexbox layout along with sticky header

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have flexbox layout wherein left layout should be scrollable but it should use only window scroll not its own scroll and left layout should be sticky when we scroll left layout.

Edit: It should work with sticky header as well.

Here's the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-glade-ewojzf?file=/src/styles.css:0-564

CSS:

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: grey;
}

#parent {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0px 24px !important;
  gap: 24px;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
}

#left {
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#right div {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 325px;
  width: 325px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: hotpink;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="parent">
      <div class="child" id="left">
        Scrollable content, but should scroll only using the window scroll, not
        it's own scroll
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
      </div>
      <div class="child" id="right">
        <div>
          Right Card <br />I should be sticky and my height should not be 100vh,
          it should be according to my content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

PS: Don't consider this duplicate. In other solutions the scroll is coming to the scrollable div not window.

Comment: Please see [ask]. Links to code on other sites aren't adequate.

Comment: Why does the right card have the text "Left Card" at the top?

Comment: That's my mistake, fixed it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add `position: sticky` for `#right div`. Like this:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 120px;
  background-color: grey;
  z-index: 99;
}

#parent {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0px 24px !important;
  gap: 24px;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 10px;
}

#left {
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#right div {
  display: flex;
  min-width: 325px;
  width: 325px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 200px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 120px;
  background-color: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/styles.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="header">Header</div>
    <div id="parent">
      <div class="child" id="left">
        Scrollable content, but should scroll only using the window scroll, not
        it's own scroll
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
        <div class="box">BOX</div>
      </div>
      <div class="child" id="right">
        <div>
          Right Card <br />I should be sticky and my height should not be 100vh,
          it should be according to my content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use the "Copy snippet to answer" button in the question to copy the code to your answer, make the changes you suggest, then you (and others) can run the code here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, i have used  "Copy snippet to answer" for my answer.

Comment: @Anh Le Hoang, Thanks for the answer. But I want the right card to have height as per it's content, now it's having height 100vh.

Comment: Hi @lazyCoder, I edited my answer. Does the result has like your expectation?

Comment: Hi, I updated my question. I also want a sticky header on top. But when I'm scrolling the right card is also scrolling till header, but I want it sticky. Can you pls provide more help on that ?

Comment: i edited my answer for your new requirement, try it @lazyCoder

Comment: I can't see the updated answer sticky which contains header, where you've updated ?

Comment: Got it, Trying now!

Comment: When i commented, i realized that i forgot click "save edits" button @lazyCoder. And then i clicked "save edits" after when i commented.